# Let a window display above a fullscreen window in GTK+

Tags: gtk, x11

I have a full-screen window (winA) and another window (winB) which is always on top.

Now I need to let winB display above winA, while winA is still above any other windows.

How to do this in GTK+? Thanks. (Maybe this needs Xlib?)

PS1: I won't use POPUP windows because it will put **all** the windows under it. I just need put winB on winA but not all the others. For example, if I am watching videos in the fullscreen mode, I wouldn't like to see winB. But if winA it's here, winB is just above it.

PS2: winA & winB are in the same program. In this case, it may simplify the solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main way to tell the window manager to keep winB above winA is through the "transient for" hint, set in GTK+ with [gtk_window_set_transient_for()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-transient-for).

If your window is not a dialog, the behavior may not come out quite how you'd like; you could try setting a semantic hint with [gtk_window_set_type_hint()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/3.16/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-set-type-hint) and see if that gets you anywhere.

But the behavior is basically going to vary with window manager (which is intended). So you kind of need to just live with that and assume people will use a WM that works how they want it to.